# Alternatives to Journal of Statistical Software?

Tags: r, software, references

I have developed an R package for a general class of regression models with applications in survival analysis. I have prepared a paper describing the package and the methods, and the applications. One possible outlet for this publication is JSS. However, it is well known that their reviewing process is very slow, taking even years to publish something there, which is rather bad for a computational contribution as things move faster than in theoretical statistics.

https://ntguardian.wordpress.com/2018/08/05/time-to-accept-it-publishing-in-the-journal-of-statistical-software/

What alternative journals are there?

Edit: I just came across the R Journal, and I am currently having a look at it. It looks like a good alternative choice.

Answer (score 2):

You can try JOSS: [Journal of Open Source Software](http://joss.theoj.org/), that is an academic journal (ISSN 2475-9066) with a formal peer review process that is designed to improve the quality of the software submitted.

They create a DOI after publication, follow the [Covenant code of conduct](http://contributor-covenant.org/) and are affiliated of the [Open Source Initiative](https://opensource.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. lt would be useful to explain what it is about the journal that make it a good choice.